# Jquery whenever has class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want jquery to always be ready to check if a class is added to my DIV, when i do normal hasClass it doesnt seem to work.

I have 2 DIV, when i scroll swipe from one to next, i want jquery to check for me wether it has class swiper-slide-visible or not.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.intro-early-life').hasClass("swiper-slide-visible")) {
        alert("Yeah!");
    }
    else {
        alert("don have");
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: you must know when the class is added since you wrote the code to add it

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesnt seem to work"?

Comment: he wants a 'class added' event handler

Comment: it just wont work, ill add my code here for you to see

Comment: I answered similar kind of question a while ago. You need to check DOMAttrModified, which is dispatched when class is added / removed. Check: http://codepen.io/zvona/pen/eGbur/ for example.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a hook plugin. Once you include it, you need to set the event listener. Here the plugin :

```
//@Author Karl-André Gagnon
$.hook = function(){
    var arg = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
    $.each(arg, function(){
        var fn = this
            if(!$.fn['hooked'+fn]){
            $.fn['hooked'+fn] = $.fn[fn];
            $.fn[fn] = (function(){
                this['hooked'+fn].apply(this, arguments);
                this.trigger(fn, arguments);
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Then you active it on all "class changing functions" :

```
$.hook('addClass', 'removeClass'); //Toggleclass already use removeclass or addclass in it function, it is useless to add it.
```

Then you bind your function :

```
$('.intro-early-life').on('addClass removeClass', function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("swiper-slide-visible")) {
        alert("Yeah!");
    }
    else {
        alert("don have");
    }
});
```

---

*Note that this only work if the class is added by one of those function. Hook cannot bind events on other function than jQuery methods. If it is a plugin that add your class, it may not work.*

Comment: unfortunately its a plugin, thanks for the effort though

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an event for add class implemented in jquery so will have to do it manually:

```
setInterval(function(){
    if($( "#thediv" ).hasClass( "theclass" )){
        //do stuff
    }
}, some_interval_time);
```

Comment: really gross but if OP wants a "class added" event then I guess this is it

Comment: instead of some_interval_time what should i put ?

Comment: its a value in milliseconds specifying how long to wait before checking again.

Comment: @user3464035 For 2 seconds, yes. depends how promptly you want the code to act. 100 should be quick enough for a fairly fast response, without stressing out the browser

Answer (score 0):

Check out fiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/x4Spz/

,It says Yes as It has class

```
<div class="intro-early-life swiper-slide-visible">
sds    
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.intro-early-life').hasClass("swiper-slide-visible")) {
        alert("Yeah!");
    }
    else {
        alert("don have");
    }
});
```